# Papyrus UML for Eclipse 2019-03 doesn't have any profiles?

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-c++, uml

I did search for some free UML tool, that I could use together with my professional growth were I will learn C++.

This way I found "Papyrus" for the Eclipse IDE. Since I did have the IDE already installed I thought this would be a good idea.

Like it says on the Papyrus page I did add "Papyrus - http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/updates/releases/2019-03" to my list and checked everything from Papyrus to be installed.

This way I did think that everything would be installed.

After this one I did found the YouTube Tutorial by GWTLecturer (e.g. UML Tutorial 3.0 - Basics of Java Class Diagrams in Eclipse with Papyrus). Even if this one is at this moment about 3 years old I thought it could help me. Since my first trial and error actions didn't work. I could not find a way to create an easy class-diagramm.

Okay he does include the option to generate Java code. And I would like this option to. Even if I do not use, if I want to use this later on or if I will still prefer to write everything by myself. At least at the beginning where I learn the basics it isn't this wrong to write it by myself, at least in my opinion.

Okay but there are the problems. 
GWTLecturer did install some GVT tool, that seems to not be available in the new eclipse edition. Okay if there won't be any problem I do not need to install it.

But I do not have any profils available or find any usefull tutorial to help with it. I would like to be able to create code in different programming languages i choose. Maybe to see if I did write them correctly.

Could someone help me please?

(With the professional training we use some online tool. But this one crys by already 3 classes in one diagramm that we use already 32% of the available space for free use. This way it is not a tool I want to use in order to train after the lessons.

(If you would say I should use some other freeware tool I am open for any ideas that use the standard UML 2.5)

Answer (score 1):

You can try following this step:

Eclipse > Help > Install New Software> Enter link: http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/updates/releases/mars/ into "Work with" field > Press Enter. After Eclipse Fletch > Into the list below > Papyrus Java > Choose what you want to install > Click Next and Follow the wizard.

I hope it work for you!